# OnCurrentIndexChange handler triggering before I select a row on the table in Wix

Tags: velo

I'm trying to get the row data from a table which is connected to a dataset. So as per the this [article](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/$w.TableRowEvent.html#rowData), since, I need the whole data of the selected row, I'm using OnCurrentIndexChange event handler to get the selected row's data from the dataset. But for some strange reason, the first row item will always be triggered on the load of the table/page.

Basically, the first row data will be selected on the load of the page/table. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jilu

Answer (score 0):

Though I couldn't get to work with `OnCurrentIndexChange` handler. But I found a work around by which I could fix this bug/issue for my application.

**Solution:**

Instead of using `OnCurrentIndexChange` handler of the dataset, I used `OnSelectRow` event handler to get the row index of the table and used that index to get the whole row data from the dataset.  More on this get method, you can find [here](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-dataset.DynamicDataset.html#getItems).

[image]

Below is the code for your reference:

```
export function tblCustomerList_rowSelect(event) {
    $w("#dsCustomer").getItems(event.rowIndex, 1)
        .then(result => {
 let selectedRow = result.items[0];
            console.log(selectedRow);

 if (selectedRow !== null) {
 let returnObj = {
 "name": selectedRow.name,
 "id": selectedRow._id
                }
                wixWindow.lightbox.close(returnObj);
            }
        })
}
```

Hope this will be helpful for people who are stuck with such kind of issue in wix.

Thanks,
Jilu